# Импорт и экспорт

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть главный файл script.js и я хочу разбить код внутри на другие файлы, а в главном файле просто их импортировать, как можно это реализовать?
Моя попытка:

```
<script src="js/script.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

```
script.js

'use strict';

import forms from './forms.js';
```

```
forms.js

export default {

    const form = document.querySelector('.footer__item__form');
    const formFilesBlock = document.querySelector('.footer__item__form__footer__files');
    const formInputFile = document.querySelector('.footer__item__form__footer__file-btn__input');
    const formInputFileLabel = document.querySelector('.footer__item__form__footer__file-btn__input-label');
    const formTitle = document.querySelector('.footer__item__form-title');
    const footerThanks = document.querySelector('.footer__item__thanks');
    const realFormOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.footer__item__form__select__option');
    const formSelectOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.select__option');
    const validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".pdf", ".gif", ".png", ".docx", ".zip", ".rar"];  
    /////////////////////// Отправка формы ///////////////////////

    formSelectOptions.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
            realFormOptions.forEach((option) => {
                if(el.dataset.value == option.getAttribute('value')) {
                    realFormOptions.forEach((el) => el.removeAttribute('selected'));
                    option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
        });
    })

    form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
        let checkPos = ''; 
        realFormOptions.forEach((el) => {
            if(el.hasAttribute('selected')) {
                checkPos = el.value;
            }
        });
        const formData = {
            name: document.querySelector('.footer__item__form__input_name').value,
            email: document.querySelector('.footer__item__form__input_email').value,
            about: document.querySelector('.footer__item__form__input_about').value,
            position: checkPos
        }
        console.log(formData);
    });

    /////////////////////// Отправка формы ///////////////////////
}
```

Comment: что не так с твоей попыткой?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Добавьте `type="module"` в `<script>`

Comment: Я так уже делал, не помогло

Comment: Обновил код и добавил html подключение

Comment: `export default {}` должен экспортировать обьект, а не кусок кода.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file